# Angular 2 rc.5 unable to refresh page after updating from rc.4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-rc5

I have just finished updating my app from rc.4 to rc.5 and I'm encountering a weird error.

When I hit `localhost:8080` I am redirected to `localhost:8080/browse` as expected, however when I then hit the browser refresh button I get the following error: `Cannot GET /browse`.

Note: Before a hash was being added to the URL, i.e. localhost:8080/#/browse but not that doesn't get added.

Here's my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: DashboardComponent,
    path: 'browse'
  }, {
    component: ProductViewportComponent,
    path: 'project/:id'
  }, {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/browse'
  }
];

export const routing: any = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: Do you use something except Angular 2? Node.js for example?

Comment: We use node, webpack, and browserify. This all worked correctly in rc.4 though using the old router.

Comment: Does editing ```redirectTo: '/browse'``` to ```redirectTo: 'browse'``` change something?

Comment: No it doesn't. This comment needs to be longer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by me unknowingly changing from the HashLocationStrategy to the PathLocationStrategy

Answer (score 0):

If you use Node.js, then you have to redirect all to index.html file.

```
app.use('*', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});
```

Don't know if `res.render` or `res.redirect` (it is not important though, I just gave you the idea).

by the way, try to edit
`redirectTo: '/browse'` to `redirectTo: 'browse'`

Comment: Ahh we actually use webpack and browserify to serve the application not node. We just use node for the package management.

Comment: Try to hold the main route ``` { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/browse' }``` at the top of the routes. I noticed that sometimes routes order is the key.

Comment: Nope that doesn't change anything.